# Discord.py Slash Commands

Tags: python

I keep getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 440, in 
import discord_slash
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_slash'

Anyone knows what to do?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, obviously, the module `discord_slash` doesn't exist!

I think you should import these instead:

```py
import discord, discord.ext, keep_alive, glob, os
```

Source tutorial: https://replit.com/talk/learn/Basic-Discord-Bot-Tutorial-Python/141781

Comment: Now it says this:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 30, in <module>
    import discord, discord.ext, keep_alive, glob, os
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keep_alive'

Comment: That means there's no `keep_alive` module, so perhaps you can try changing it to `import discord, discord.ext, glob, os`!

Comment: Still this: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 441, in <module>
    import discord_slash
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_slash'

Comment: Oh that means you should delete the line that imports `discord_slash` :)